# Unable to Access Component Prop From Within Sort Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and attempting to build a simple, sortable table. The data that will populate the table is stored as an array of objects (`data` variable). I want to:

1. Pass my  component a 'column' prop. This prop will be used as a reference to the object property I want to sort the table by (`<TableBody column='rank' />` should result in the data array being sorted by the 'rank' property).
2. In the `<TableBody />` component, use a sort function to sort the `data` array by the object property passed in as a prop.
3. Render sorted table rows.

Here is the code that isn't working for me:

```
const data = [
    { name: 'Jim', rank: 2 },
    { name: 'Ed', rank: 3 },
    { name: 'Jane', rank: 4 },
    { name: 'Lin', rank: 1 },
]

export function TableBody({ column }) {
    data.sort((a, b) => a.column - b.column)
    const tableRows = data.map(row => {
        return (
            <tr key={row.name}>
                <td>{row.name}</td>
                <td>{row.rank}</td>
            </tr>
        )
    })
    return <tbody>{tableRows}</tbody>
}

export default function Standings() {
    return (
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Rank</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <TableBody column='rank' />
        </table>
    )
}
```

If I don't try to reference the column prop in my sort function and instead use `data.sort((a, b) => a.rank - b.rank)` I get the results I'd expect. This isn't a solution I can use because I want to be able to pass different object properties as props based on user actions like clicking a table header.

Comment: Try: `data.sort((a, b) => a[column] - b[column])`. Your code is trying to access the `column` property where you need to use the value of `column` that you're passing into the component.

Comment: Thanks for the response! When I try this I get a SyntaxError...

Comment: [I've just tested it and it works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/g93fdce4/).

Comment: Apologies, I had left a '.' in by mistake. This is the correct answer! Thank you for the help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you think to try `data.sort((a, b) => a[column] - b[column])` this?

Comment: can you log what's the value of "column" prop ? maybe u are render somewhere this tableBody component . data.sort((a, b) => a[column || "rank"] - b[column || "rank"]) you can try this also